# HSV values using openCV or javaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv

I want to track a color within an image. I use the following code (javaCV):

```
//Load initial image.
iplRGB = cvLoadImage(imageFile, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
//Prepare for HSV 
iplHSV = cvCreateImage(iplRGB.cvSize(), iplRGB.depth(), iplRGB.nChannels());
//Transform RGB to HSV
cvCvtColor(iplRGB, iplHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

//Define a region of interest.
//minRow = 0; maxRow = iplHSV.height();
//minCol = 0; maxCol = iplHSV.width();
minRow = 197; minCol = 0; maxRow = 210; maxCol = 70;

//Print each HSV for each pixel of the region.
for (int y = minRow; y < maxRow; y++){
   for (int x = minCol; x < maxCol; x++) {
      CvScalar pixelHsv = cvGet2D(iplHSV, y, x);
      double h = pixelHsv.val(0); 
      double s = pixelHsv.val(1);
      double v = pixelHsv.val(2);
      String line = y + "," + x + "," + h + "," + s + "," + v;
      System.out.println(line);
   }
}
```

I can easily find out the minimum and maximum for HUE and SAT from the output. Let's call then minHue, minSat, maxHue and maxSat (not fancy hey !). Then I execute this code:

```
    iplMask = cvCreateImage(iplHSV.cvSize(), iplHSV.depth(), 1);
    CvScalar min = cvScalar(minHue, minSat, 0, 0);
    CvScalar max = cvScalar(maxHue, maxSat, 255 ,0);
    cvInRangeS(iplHSV, min, max, iplMask);
```

When I show the iplMask, should not I see the region of interest entirely white ? I don't, I see the contour being white but the inside of the rectangle is black. I must mess with something but I do not understand what.

I know that Hue is in [0..179] with OpenCV and Sat and Val are in [0..255] but since I use the values displayed by openCV I would think I do not have to rescale...

Anyway, I am lost. Can somebody explain ? Thanks.

Comment: With 8-bit images, [according to the doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cvtColor), all HSV values are scaled to fit within 0 and 255... Why do you say Hue is limited to 179?

Comment: @SamuelAudet It looks like he is right, according to the doc. RGB2HSV first converts S and V to floats. It says that on output, S and V are in the range 0..1, and H is 0..360. It then says that to convert to 8bit, S and V are multiplied by 255, and H is divided by 2, telling us that H is in the range 0..180

Comment: Oops, looks like that is the case. Anyway, looking back at the documentation of `cvInRangeS()`, it looks like we would have to `CvScalar max = cvScalar(maxHue+1, maxSat+1, 255 ,0);` to get a fully white mask.